# Compute the sum recursively by dividing array

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to create a function to compute the sum of elements in the array recursively. I wanted to try the approach of halving the array every iteration.

Here's what I have so far.

```
int sumRec(int *A, int n, int start, int end)
{
     if (start == end){
         return A[end];
     }
     mid = n/2;
     return sumRec(A, n, start, mid) + sumRec(A, n, start, mid + 1);
}
```

Am I on the right track? 
Thanks.

Comment: Is it working or not?

Comment: As I can see `mid = (start+end)/2`. And may be it's useful split the function on two: non-recursive with parameters `A` and `n`, and recursive with parameters `A`, `start`, and `end`.

Comment: Why are people afraid to *try* their code? Does nobody think of creating an empty project to test in? Are they not aware of sandboxes like ideone.com?

Comment: shouldn't the second call be `sumRec(A,n,mid+1,end)`? And, as @Mark said, `mid=(start+end)/2`, as `n` is a constant, so your recursion does not end this way (all four parameters for the first call in the sum are always the same).

Comment: I guess the answer would be "yes, you are on the right track". Did you try debugging?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track... except nobody can understand why on earth would anybody want to calculate sum with recursion. It is one of the worst examples of recursion misuse I have seen. :) Why? Well, you won't probably kill your stack with this specific example but definitely you will have serious memory underperformance due to caching.

Comment: I know programming is often taught on paper. But I think that's a bad approach. If setting up a compiler is too much hassle, please use online compilers like http://ideone.com or http://cpp.sh. They will immediately tell you if your code compiles and works.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass n to the function.That's not needed.
Currently your program will run into an *infinite recursion.*

You can use

`mid = (start+end)/2;`

There are many more errors in your code.

Here's a similar code that could do the job

```
int sumRec(int *A, int start, int end)
{
     if (start <= end)
     {
        int mid = (start+end)/2;
        return A[mid] + sumRec(A,start, mid-1) + sumRec(A,mid+1,end);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider optimising based on [tail and non-tail recursion](https://www.quora.com/What-is-tail-recursion-Why-is-it-so-bad). In your, example the calculation is done after the return of the recursive call.